# Angular.js Rails routing doesn't work as expected

Tags: ruby, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm having some problems when try to load Angular views in my Rails app. But if I do in the page `{{1+3}} it gives me the correct result as 4. So I believe it's something to do with routes.

The following is my stack:

- `angular 1.2.20`
- `angular-ui-router (latest)`
- `rails 4.1.1`

The following are my files.

app/assets/javascript/app.js

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
       $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
       $stateProvider
         .state('home',{
            url: 'home',
            template: "<h1>Test</h1>"
         });
         $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

app/views/layout/application.html.erb

```
 # Please note I have added 'app' in the body tag 
 <div ng-view>
   <%= yield %>
 </div>
```

config/routes

```
# Please note I have a controller called home
root 'home#index'
get '*path' => 'home#index'
```

What I'm expecting is when I go to `http://localhost:3000` I should see the 'Test' inside the div. But it's not happening and there are no errors in the JS console as well. What can I try next?

Comment: not fully sure about all your stuff, but I would expect/use `url: '/home'`

Comment: Do you have a rails template to fill with `<%= yield %>` and `<a ui-sref="home"></a>` tag in it?